# Breakpoint problem in MS Visual C# 2008 Express Edition

Tags: c#

Whenever I place a breakpoint somewhere in my C# code file and then debug the program, the application stops responding. Everything's fine without the breakpoint. What gives?

I am talking about VS.

Comment: Are you talking about your program or about Visual Studio? – Maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint can be helpful.

Comment: Well, you found an extraordinary unusual bug.  This is something that gets a workout hundreds of thousands a time each day.  And has never been reported before in any forum I've seen.  Try connect.microsoft.com to document the bug you've found.  You'll need to provide repro code to help MSFT troubleshoot the issue, your entire project is best.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the breakpoint is doing what its supposed to do, pause your program at the point in the code.  If you press the play button, your application will resume until it hits the next breakpoint